# Kohana HMVC Request factory

Tags: kohana, request, controller

Здравствуйте! Не подскажите, как в Kohana 3.3 обращаться к другим контроллерам. Я делаю так:

```
class Controller_Main  extends Controller_Template
{
    public $template = 'static';

    public function action_index()
    {


        $countries = Request::factory('place/country')->execute();

        //print_r($response);
    }


}

class Controller_Place  extends Controller
{


    public function action_country()
    {
        $location = new Model_Location();
        return $location->get_countries();
    }
}


class Model_Location extends Model 
{

    public function get_countries()
    {
        return DB::select('name','country_id')
                    ->from('countries')
                    ->order_by('country_id')
                    ->execute()->as_array();
    }
    public function get_country_regions($country_id)
    {

    }


}
```

Но при распечатке выходит следующая информация:

```
Response Object ( [_status:protected] => 200 [_header:protected] => HTTP_Header Object ( [_accept_content:protected] => [_accept_charset:protected] => [_accept_encoding:protected] => [_accept_language:protected] => [storage:ArrayObject:private] => Array ( ) ) [_body:protected] => [_cookies:protected] => Array ( ) [_protocol:protected] => HTTP/1.1 )
```

Comment: А зачем вам из одного контроллера обращаться в другой? Это две разные сущности. В какой контроллер/action обратиться решает роутинг. Допускается наследование, к примеру, `TopNewsController` extends `NewsController`. Все остальные связи должны происходить на уровне модели.

Comment: @romeo HMVC - это подход, в котором финальная страница может формироваться из вывода нескольких контроллеров.

Comment: @Etki: Благодарю, освежил свои знания.

Comment: В старых версиях после execute () обращались еще к response.  Google выводит ссылки на статьи 2011 -2012 годов. Поэтому решение проблемы я не нашел

Comment: @murash: А что выводит `var_dump(Request::factory('place/country')->execute()->__toString());`? Должен вывести body объекта Response.

Comment: Выводит string(0) ""

Answer (score 1):

Kohana позволяет вам использовать ваши классы откуда угодно. (Основной принцип MVC).

Кохана подгружает классы по названию файлов если файл(путь) указаны не верно в название класса кохана отбросит его как внешний код.

Как например класс: Controller_V1_Api_User
Кохана будет искать в: application/classes/Controller/V1/Api/User.php

Есть ряд условий на расположение классов. 
Так же важно знать что кахана подгрузить любой класс который будет расположен в папке kohana*

Например:
application/classes/Kohana/TestClass.php